# Different number of parameters between client and contract functions

Tags: function

From this repository: https://github.com/dabit3/polygon-ethereum-nextjs-marketplace

Look at `createToken` function inside the JavaScript file (`pages/create-nft.js`):

```
let listingPrice = await contract.getListingPrice()
listingPrice = listingPrice.toString()
let transaction = await contract.createToken(url, price, { value: listingPrice })
await transaction.wait()
```

And from Solidity contract:

```
/* Mints a token and lists it in the marketplace */
function createToken(string memory tokenURI, uint256 price) public payable returns (uint) {
    _tokenIds.increment();
    uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIds.current();

    _mint(msg.sender, newTokenId);
    _setTokenURI(newTokenId, tokenURI);
    createMarketItem(newTokenId, price);
    return newTokenId;
}
```

Why there's a third parameter inside `createToken` function, since the contract has only 2?

Comment: I ask because it sure is not a developer oversight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `createToken` is marked as `payable`, which means it can accept Ether transfers to it. And that's exactly what is happening here: `await contract.createToken(url, price, { value: listingPrice })` means we provide two regular parameters and one extra parameter which states how much Ethers (denominated in wei) we want to send with the transaction.

You can see this documented here: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-functionsSend , look at the `value` override.